# Problems with generating a unique ID in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I have a worksheet - created for users data entry,
where I created a unique SurveyCode
(consists of a row number + file name):
[image]

Here is the formula I used to generate SurveyCode:

```
      =CONCATENATE(ROW(Sheet1!A1),TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1),
        FIND("[",CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1))+1,255),".xl",REPT(" ",255)),255)))
```

I take Row() from a separate Sheet1, because if user decides to delete one of the records in the worksheet, then one of my **SurveyCode** formula is broken and I will see **#REF!** error instead **4ClientSatisfactionSurvey**, for example

and my changed formula will look as:

```
      =CONCATENATE(ROW(#REF!),TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A6),
         FIND("[",CELL("filename",Sheet1!A6))+1,255),".xl",REPT(" ",255)),255)))
```

with **ROW(#REF!)** instead of **ROW(A4)**

So, I decided to store Row() in a separate sheet. Even when user will decide to delete record, in that case my SurveyCode will still be kept.

But I am still having another problem - if - after record deletion prospective user will create a new record - it will not be unique, but will repeat one of the previous row numbers from my sheet1.

For example - if client would delete **4ClientSatisfactionSurvey** record from the worksheet, and then will add a new record - the new SurveyCode will = **7ClientSatisfactionSurvey** and not **8ClientSatisfactionSurvey**

I think, my problem is in the 1st part of my formula - I am not sure how to correctly generate a unique "number" part of my SurveyCode.

Please, help...

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to create an absolute secure way of unique ID in Excel **based on formulas**, because it can be modified/deleted, causing everything to fail. Best way would be typing the values. You should consider using VBA for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a dynamic range.

Assume your data is in Sheet1, Column A

Click on "Name Manager" (Formulas tab of the ribbon)
Click "New"

Name: `myRange`
Scope: `Workbook`
Refers to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1)`

This creates a range that automatically changes sizes when new data is added or rows are deleted.

You reference cells with `INDEX()`, so, on a separate sheet
`=INDEX(myRange,1)` is the first cell
`=INDEX(myRange,ROW())` is whatever cell in the corresponding row

---

**CAUTION**: watch your index values and use conditional statements to trap out of range errors

---

**WARNING**: `COUNTA()` only counts non-blank cells, if there are empty rows then you must adjust the formula to count them

---

*NOTE*: you can fix the range to a constant number of rows by referencing a helper cell

*Example*: If 20 is entered in `Sheet2!A1` and `myRange` refers to `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,Sheet2!$A$1,1)` then `myRange` will always be rows 1-20 regardless of inserted or deleted rows

---

*Having said all of that, a well designed VBA solution will be more secure and easier to use.*

---

Comment: Tried and didnt work (I probably do something wrong)
My data are in  ClientSatisfactionForm (sheet name), Column AC5 - starting column
So, based on your help I modified your formula as  " =OFFSET(ClientSatisfaction Form!$AC$5,0,0,COUNTA(ClientSatisfactionForm!AC:AC),1) "
Then, on a separate Sheet2 I created a formula for the 1st cell - A1 = INDEX(myRange, Row(A1))    Getting error - #Value?  in both my main sheet ClientSatisfactionForm and in Sheet2

Comment: I wonder if there way to create this in vba as suggested...  Will try to research

Comment: @Hell-1931 Your formula looks correct, check the name manager to ensure the range name is not mispelled.  The range name must match the name in the formula, in this case "myRange"